# Did the actor Wylie Watson play the role of waiter in The Lady Vanishes?

Tags: casting, the-lady-vanishes, the-39-steps

Was the actor, Wylie Watson, who played Mr. Memory in The 39 Steps (1935), also the waiter on the train working with the bad guys in The Lady Vanishes (1938)?

Answer (score 1):

[IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0030341/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ql_1) doesn't list Wylie Watson as any character in The Lady Vanishes.

Therefore, you must be confusing that waiter on the train with Wylie Watson. Nor he is mentioned in this cast list from the movie.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but that's why I'm asking.  He looks like the same actor; they''e both Hitchcock films; and no one else is credited with that role.  I think it's Wylie.  How can we find out?

Comment: Yes, they both are Hitchcock's films, but IMDb doesn't show him credited. If he played that character, he'd be credited given he was a great actor in that era. I looked through the movie credits and cast list mentioned on IMDb but none of them mention Wylie Watson.